# I am trying to read configuration from appsettings.json but I am getting null when I run my application

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-mvc, asp.net-core-8

Here is my code:

```
public class YouTubeShowsServices 
{
    private IConfiguration _config;
    
    string YouTubeApiKey;
    string YoutubeAppName;
    string YoutubePlaylistId;

    public YouTubeShowsServices(IConfiguration configuration)
    {
        _config = configuration;

        YouTubeApiKey =_config["YouTube:Key"];
        YoutubeAppName = _config["YouTube:AppName"];
        YoutubePlaylistId = _config["YouTube:PlayListId"];
    }
```

The variables `YouTubeApiKey`, `YouTubeAppName` and `YoutubePlaylistId` are getting set to `null`.

Here is my `appsettings.json`:

```
"YouTube": 
{
    "Key": "AIzaSyDmGZCNbxkhmS5FW-FEhzK94z0J1WWVavE",
    "PlayListId": "PLwW36SAh95SUivPyG1eUxLM8v4rjwnEfT",
    "AppName": "LiveStandup"
}
```

I am trying to read the configuration from `appsettings.json`, but my variables end up being null - can anyone help me with this code?

Comment: It should work fine By Default, make sure that you register your service to the services containers `builder.Services.AddSingleton<YouTubeShowsServices>()` ... or how do you instantiate `YouTubeShowsServices`

Comment: @IbramReda I have done same but not working

Comment: `appsettings.json` is a default [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration/?view=aspnetcore-8.0) ... and I have copied your code to new project, and it works just fine! .... do you change the configurations sources in `Program.cs`

Comment: I test your code in HomeController and I can get the result like: https://i.stack.imgur.com/IedXD.png  , What's your program.cs like ?

Comment: This is my program.cs
`using LiveStandup.Web.Services;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);
var _config = builder.Configuration;

// Add services to the container.
builder.Services.AddRazorPages();
builder.Services.AddSingleton<YouTubeShowsServices>();
`

Comment: What's your using LiveStandup.Web.Services; ? not using projectname; ?

Comment: @Qing Guo it is namespace where my code YouTubeShowsServices is

Comment: That's strange, My mvc project works fine, you could create a new project to test it.

Answer (score 1):

1. **Add NuGet Package**:

   To include the required NuGet package, use the following command:

   ```bash
   NuGet: Install-Package Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Binder
   ```
2. **Consolidate Controller Configuration**:

   Consolidate the desired controller configuration under a single category, such as "EmailSettings", in the `appsettings.json` file:

   ```json
   {
     "EmailSettings": {
       "EmailTemplatesPath": "EmailTemplates",
       "Email": "aa@aa.com"
     }
   }
   ```

   **Step 3:**

   Create a class named `EmailSettings.cs` within your Web API project:

   ```cs
   public class EmailSettings
   {
       public string EmailTemplatesPath { get; set; }
       public string Email { get; set; }
   }
   ```

   **Step 4:**

   Associate your configuration values with an instance of the `EmailSettings` class in `Startup.cs`, and inject this object into the Dependency Injection container:

   In `Startup.cs`:

   ```cs
   public void ConfigureServices(IServiceCollection services)
   {
       // ...
       EmailSettings emailSettings = new EmailSettings();
       Configuration.GetSection("EmailSettings").Bind(emailSettings);
       services.AddSingleton(emailSettings);
   }
   ```

   **Step 5:**

   You can now easily include your configuration in the constructor of the API controller to make a request:

   Example controller for Web API:

   ```cs
   [Route("api/[controller]")]
   [ApiController]
   public class ValuesController : ControllerBase
   {
       private readonly EmailSettings _emailSettings;

       public ValuesController(EmailSettings emailSettings)
       {
           _emailSettings = emailSettings;
       }

       // Other controller methods...
   }
   ```

   Now, your `ValuesController` has access to the `EmailSettings` configured in your `appsettings.json` file.